# How to use pthreading in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I was given this question to solve using multithreading:

An interesting way of calculating π (pi) is to use a technique known as Monte Carlo, which involves randomization.  This technique works as follows:  Suppose you have a circle inscribed within a square, as shown below.  Assume that the radius of this circle is 1.  First, generate a series of random points as simple (x, y) coordinates.  These points must fall within the Cartesian coordinates that bound the square.  Of the total number of random points that are generated, some will occur within the circle.

[visual of circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/080UJ.png)

Next, estimate π (pi) by performing the following calculation:
π = 4 x (number of points in circle) / (total number of points)

Write a multithreaded version of this algorithm in C that uses pthreads to create one or more separate threads to generate a number of random points.  The thread will count the number of points that occur within the circle and store that result in a global variable.  When this thread has exited, the parent thread will calculate and output the estimated value of π (pi).  It is worth experimenting with the number of random points generated.  As a general rule, the greater the number of points, the closer the approximation to π (pi).

I feel like I am close to getting this but I need some help. here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // For random(), RAND_MAX
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define total 1200

int checkvalue(int r, float x, float y)
{
    float dis,d;
    int count = 0;
    //Considering center as (0,0) as per the picture
    dis = x*x + y*y;
    d = r*r;
    if(dis == d)
    {
        printf("\nPoint is on the circle\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(dis>d)
        {
            printf("Point is outside the circle\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Point is inside the circle\n");
            return 1;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

void* CalPi(void* data)
{
    int me = *((int*)data);
    int max = 1, min = -1,r,p,count = 0;
    float x[total], y[total],pi;

    //Radius given is 1
    r = 1;
    /* thread identifying number */ // put the entire logic over here to get the co-ordinates (randomly) and checking them based on the conditions we
    for(int i = 0; i< total; i++)
    {
        x[i] = (2 * ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX) - 1) ;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i< total; i++)
    {
        y[i] = (2 * ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX) - 1) ;
    }
    printf("Point are :");
    for(int i = 0; i< total; i++)
    {
        printf("(%f,%f)\n", x[i],y[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i< total; i++)
    {
        p = checkvalue(r,x[i],y[i]);
        if (p == 1)
        {
            printf("Point : (%f,%f)\n",x[i],y[i]);
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("count = %d", count);
    pi = (float) 4 * (count / (total * 1.0));
    printf("\nThe value of pi : %f ", pi);

}

void main()
{
    int thread_id; pthread_t thread_val; //thread's structure
    int t1 = 1; // thread 1 identifying number
    int t2 = 2; //Creating a new thread which will execute 'CalPi()'
    thread_id = pthread_create(&thread_val, NULL, CalPi, (void*)&t1); // executing 'CalPi()' in the main thread as well
    CalPi((void*)&t2);

    }
```

Comment: I don't think you're meant to be calculating pi twice with 2 threads, but getting the threads to add more data points so that your 1 estimate of pi is more accurate.  For this your threads must access a shared resource.  To be able to do that safely you'll need a mutex.  I leave it as an exercise to the OP to read up about what they are.

Comment: Just copying the assignment you got and you code is not gonna help you here. You better try to analyze where your problem is and be more specific about it.

Comment: @UKMonkey It's a common approach to calculate it multiple times (1 per thread), then take the average. This also directly provides an estimate for the accuracy of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is clearly homework I will only provide pseudo code (I don't want to take away your learning experience). Here are some pointers on how you could solve the excercise:

Global variables:

`long total` - the number of iterations per thread (can also be a `#define`).

`long K` - Must be larger than the highest thread identifier.

`long count[K]` - Thread counters. Each thread will update it's counter with the number of random points that were inside the circle.

Main:

1. Set a value for `total` (could be global volatile variable).
2. create threads
3. Wait for threads
4. Sum results
5. Print total result

Thread:

1. Loop `total` times
2. For each loop iteration, generate a random point and add the result of `checkvalue` to the count for the thread.

Note:

Each thread should have a separate count variable (for example in a global array using the thread identifier number as index). You don't  need to store the result for each point, just the count. If they would use the same count variable, access to it would have to be synchronized, and that would decrease performance.

Note 2:

The use of global variables is not really the best way to handle communication with the threads. It is, however, the easiest way, so for a beginning thread programmer it is good enough.